# ethstats on http://homestead.test:8081 don't display my nodes

Tags: ethereum, homestead

I am following this guide https://www.sitepoint.com/puppeth-introduction/ to create my private ethereum network. Although ethstats looks fine when I install it, it does not display the nodes of the next steps (for example boot node). This happens when I pick for domain homestead.test .
If my domain is 192.168.10.10 the nodes display fine. Why is this happening? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the domain name is not connected to the IP.
Try to add the correct setting the the etc/hosts file. (You may need to edit the file as administrator).

The file is located at windows: : c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

In case you are using mac this can help: https://help.nexcess.net/how-to-find-the-hosts-file-on-my-mac

```
192.168.10.10  homestead.test
```